# use jsonSlurper.parseText for text that has dash

Tags: groovy

How can I use jsonSlurper.parseText to parse "807-000" that has dash in it with groovy ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are generating the below string for parsing:

```
[807-000]
```

What I think you wanted is an json array containing a string:

```
["807-000"]
```

You could generate that json yourself:

```
def arr2 = "[" + arr.collect({ '"' + it + '"' }).join(",") + "]"
```

But why reinvent the wheel, when you can do it like this:

```
def arr2 = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what exactly do you want to do. parseText() is waiting for json to be input. I suggest several options for parsing.

```
def text = jsonSlurper.parseText("""{ "key": "807-000" } """)
```

Or did you mean that before the dash is the key, and after it is the value? If so then you can try this:

```
def map = "807-000".split("-").toSpreadMap()
map.each {row ->
    def parsedText = jsonSlurper.parseText("""{ "${row.key}": "${row.value}" } """)
    println(parsedText)
}
```

output is = [807:000]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use jsonSlurper.parseText to parse "807-000" that has dash
> in it with groovy ?

I am not sure what the challenge actually is.  Something I can think of is possibly you are having trouble using Groovy property access to retrieve the value of a key when the key has a hyphen in it.  You can do that by quoting the property name:

```
String jsonString = '''
    {"807-000":"Eight O Seven"}
'''

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText(jsonString)

// quote the property name which
// contains a hyphen...
String description = json.'807-000'

assert description == 'Eight O Seven'
```

Comment: hi , no my challenge is convert the string "807-000" to array that can map on it , but when I parse "807-000" , groovy cant handle hyphen as a element of array I added photo of problem to the post

Comment: " my challenge is convert the string "807-000" to array that can map on it" - When you convert "807-000" to an array, what should be in the array?  Are you looking for an array that contains the characters `8`, `0`, `7`, `-`, `0`, `0`, and `0`?